# Alamo Fire and Swift Cannot convert value of type '[String : String]' to expected argument type 'HTTPHeaders?'

Tags: swift, xcode

```
func requestWithRetries(tag:String, url:String, maxRetry:Int = 3, expectJSONArray:Bool,  completion:@escaping jsonCompletion) {
    var headers = [String:String]()
    let params = [String:AnyObject]()
    let token = "UNVCRDFR5M8BW0P72KU6"
    headers["Authorization"] = token
    
    let alamoRequest = alamoFire.request(serviceURL + url, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers) .validate() .responseJSON { response in
```

// Cannot convert value of type '[String : String]' to expected argument type 'HTTPHeaders?'

```
        switch response.result {
        case let .success(value):
            if let json = response.result.value {
                let result = JSON(json) //Value of type 'Result<Any, AFError>' has no member 'value'
                if let serverMessage = Utils.stringJSON(result["message"]) {
                    self.didFail(tag: tag, error: serverMessage, code: nil)
                    return
                }
                Utils().saveDebugData(result.description, fileName: tag)
                self.didRecieve(tag: tag, result: result)
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

`HTTPHeaders` has an init method which takes a dictionary

```
...headers: HTTPHeaders(headers)
```

but you should take the opportunity and refactor your code for example

- `responseDecodable` can deserialize the JSON directly into structs, `responseJSON` is deprecated anyway.
- `SwiftyJSON` has become obsolete since the introduction of `Codable` in Swift 4.
- `Alamofire` *speaks* `async/await`.

And `parameters` is `[String:Any]`, not `[String:AnyObject]`.